# nginx basic authentication on all pages except a specific URL and it's follow

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, nginx, .htpasswd

Am implementing basic authentication on my Ubuntu server. I want to except url and all it follows. example, the url i want to except is sample.com/sample/ and all of it follows like sample.com/sample/1, sample.com/sample/2, sample.com/sample/samdsFFGRwd12, sample.com/sample/FHFEdsa1g65

How to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude URL from the basic authentication of nginx, need to add in your nginx conf something like:

```
location /sample/ {
    auth_basic off;
}
```