# How to exclude a route from basic authentication on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have nginx server, and there is a Django App running behind it and the server is protected through Basic_auth authentication. what i want is to exclude some endpoints from authentication for example:

`/api/v1/testpoint/?search=48`

i tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431499/nginx-basic-authentication-on-all-pages-except-a-specific-url-and-its-follow) but i get 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i added something like this to my `mysite`:

```
location /api/v1/testpoint/ {
    auth_basic off;
}
```

which succeeded in disabling the Basic_authentication for all request to `/api/v1/testpoint/` .

But i was getting `404` error because when requests arrived for `/api/v1/testpoint/?search=48` Nginx tried to serve the request relative to its default public web root.

but since i was running django app it should forward the requests to the django app not serving them relatively to default public web root.

nginx was communicating with the django app through uWsgi server which was running on port 9090.

so i modified the above block:

```
location /api/v1/testpoint/ {
    auth_basic  off;
    uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9090;
    include  uwsgi_params;
}
```

and that solved the problem.